# Copy table info into another table

Tags: php, select, mysqli, insert

I have database table `kladilnica` with 37 values, I want to make the users can send tickets each other, so I have created another table called `ticket` but that table have 38 values including `receiverName` so i can easy check who is the receiver and who can see the ticket. I'm going with w3schools example of copying table info and pasting into another table ex. (`$sql = "INSERT INTO ticket (senderName, receiverName, Date) SELECT Username, '', Date FROM kladilnica WHERE ticket_id='".$ticketID."'";`) this example works well but I have a minor modifications in my example. In the `SELECT` part i have nothing to select from the `kladilnica` to get the `receiverName` and display it into `ticket` **what should I do to get and write the receiverName into `ticket` table**?

Comment: I personally Cant understand anything.

Comment: i'm sorry but i tried as hard as i can to explain... edited..

Comment: "excuse me for the bad English i hope you will understand." ? I can't understand a thing..

Comment: Ah - I think I see what you are getting at.

Personally, I would get the username data from the existing table first, validate it and create the inbound query to the ticket table separately.

Comment: Question is: Where is the receiverName stored or do you have it in a variable in a script that is calling the query? Then you would write: $sql = "INSERT INTO ticket (senderName, receiverName, Date) SELECT Username, '".$receiverName."', Date FROM kladilnica WHERE ticket_id='".$ticketID."'"; (and add security for SQL injection of course...)

Comment: `receiverName` is second row in `ticket` table and i have a variable for the input field called `$ticketReceiver`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ticket (senderName, receiverName, Date) SELECT Username, '".$receiverName."', Date FROM kladilnica WHERE ticket_id='".$ticketID."'";
```

(and add security for SQL injection of course...)